# Matching outermost parentheses

Tags: regex, .net-core

Suppose I have a text like

```
compute(max(a,b), min(c,d)) - fix(e)
```

I want to extract two strings, the outermost parentheses:

```
(max(a,b), min(c,d))

(e)
```

using a regular expression in .NET. I've already tried several solutions, but none works as hoped:

- `\((?:[^()]|(?<open> \( )|(?<-open> \) ))+(?(open)(?!))\)` matches `(a,b)`, `(c,d)` and `(e)`
- `\([^\(\)]+?\)` does the same
- `\(.+\)` matches `(max(a,b), min(c,d)) - fix(e)`
- `\(.+?\)` matches `(max(a,b)`, `(c,d)`, `(e)`

I can't find a way to say "if you match an open parenthesis and you're inside parentheses ignore it, but keep going on". How can I match all and only the outermost parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, the spaces have meaning in a regex.

You could update the pattern to

```
\((?:[^()]|(?<open>\()|(?<-open>\)))+(?(open)(?!))\)
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%28%29%5d%7c%28%3f%3copen%3e%5c%28%29%7c%28%3f%3c-open%3e%5c%29%29%29%2b%28%3f%28open%29%28%3f!%29%29%5c%29&i=compute%28max%28a%2cb%29%2c+min%28c%2cd%29%29+-+fix%28e%29)